# writing pdf from javascript/cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, pdf, stream

In our mobile application (cordova+html4) we have a requirement to display the PDF from a stream. We have a service which returns pdf stream. We would like to store that stream to a temp folder location of the mobile and display the PDF. 
The below sample java sample java code does the exact thing what I need. But how can I achive this functionality on java script? I mean reading a binary stream in java script.

```
String fileURL = "https://1/////4/xyz";
String saveDir = "D:/Works";
try {
    URL url = new URL(fileURL);
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url
            .openConnection();
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("TOKEN",
            "ghZtxnPfpJ63FgdT/59V+5zFTKHRdwm6rIfGJC+0B5W5CJ9pG33od7l+/L6S8R56");
    int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Reseponse Code = " + responseCode);

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        String fileName = "";
        String disposition = httpConn
                .getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
        String contentType = httpConn.getContentType();
        int contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();

        if (disposition != null) {
            // extracts file name from header field
            int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
            if (index > 0) {
                fileName = disposition.substring(index + 10,
                        disposition.length() - 1);
            }
        } else {
            // extracts file name from URL
            fileName = fileURL.substring(fileURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                    fileURL.length());
        }

        System.out.println("Content-Type = " + contentType);
        System.out.println("Content-Disposition = " + disposition);
        System.out.println("Content-Length = " + contentLength);
        System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);

        // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
        InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
        String saveFilePath = saveDir + File.separator + fileName;

        // opens an output stream to save into file
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                saveFilePath);

        int bytesRead = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

        System.out.println("File downloaded");
    } else {
        System.out
                .println("No file to download. Server replied HTTP code: "
                        + responseCode);
    }
    httpConn.disconnect();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thre's two libraries that you may want to have a look at :

[jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) if you're trying to generate pdf from javascript and

[pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) if you're trying to implement a pdf viewer in your interface.

One of those two should do the trick for you.